# В какое значение устанавливается свойство position у элемента с float

Tags: вёрстка, css

Интересует в какое значение устанавливается свойство position у элемента с float. Вроде бы элемент не выпадает из потока, значит absolute & fixed отпадают. Получается что остается только relative & static. Однако по своему поведению плавающему блоку не подходит ни то не другое. Интересует именно, то что буде в свойстве position, то есть теоретическая часть, так как с поведение float на практике трудностей не возникает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот, что показывает](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/W2Sg9/) выявление данного свойства с помощью jQuery. Т.е. если верить этому способу, то элемент имеет **position: static**

Comment: Эм. Может из-за того, что `position` по умолчанию установлен на `static`? Я как-то рассчитывал увидеть тут более развёрнутый ответ с обьяснением того, какое свойство над каким "доминирует" и т.д. Хотя, самому лень писать подобный ответ `:)`